# how to add words that must be written in data input, if the word is not input then a loop will occur in the data?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, try-catch, do-while

example :

1. Input your address [must be ended with 'street'] : red
   Input must be ended with 'street' !
2. Input your address [must be ended with 'street'] : red street

how to loop the input question if the inputter does not add the word 'street'

Answer (score 1):

It **could** be something like this (read the comments in code):

```
// Keyboard input Stream. The JVM will auto-Close this when app ends.
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
    
// To hold supplied Address.
String address = "";
    
// Continue looping for as long as the `address` variable is empty.
while (address.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Enter Address: -> ");  // Ask User for Adress:
    address = userInput.nextLine().trim();   // Get entire keyboard input line:
    /* Validating User Input using the String#matches() method and a
       small Regular Expression (RegEx): `(?i)` Letter case insensative,
       `.*` Any number of alphanumerical characters, ` street` must 
       end with a whitespace and `street` in any letter case.      */
    if (!address.matches("(?i).* street")) {
        // Not a match! Inform User and allow to try again...
        System.out.println("Invalid Address. Must end with the word "
                             + "'Street'. Try Again...");
        System.out.println();
        address = "";  // Empty `address` to ensure reloop.
    }
}

// If we get to this point then validation was successful.
    
// Display the Address in Console Window:
System.out.println("Supplied Address: -> " + address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything? If not, you can break down into the following and build up your code step-by-step.

#### Which loop to use?

You should first choose a loop to start with. **For-loop** or **Do-while loop**?
For a **For-loop**, it will repeat the logic inside the loop for a given number of times.
For a **Do-While loop**, it will repeat until your logic does not fulfil any more.

#### What function can be used to read an Input?

The simplest class that can be used to read an Input will be [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

#### How will be the code look like?

Because you know that you have to repeat your Input logic until **street** is being inputted at the end. So you probably end up having something like this:

```
Define some useful variables here if necessary
Loop Body Start (Repeat Condition here if you choose for-loop)
  Ask for Input
Loop Body End (Repeat Condition here if you choose do-while loop)
```

Note that the word **automatically** means that you can do nothing if your requirement is not met. Because a loop is meant to be repeat if your stated requirement is not yet finished.